# Can the sap conversational AI chat bot be exported/stored on github?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, sap-conversational-ai

I have been trying to find out ways to export and save a chat bot agent(by agent i mean intents, skills etc) on cai.tools.sap to github.

The only possible way to clone or copy a chat bot on cai is by its "fork" button. However, the fork button lets you copy the agent within the cai platform. I want to be able to export this chat bot as a json file or something like that.

Thanks for the help!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed with SAP support as of May 2020. The answer is NO.